# Why should I STILL use --with-boost option when I defined the PATH variable

Tags: ubuntu, boost, configure

I would love to hear your explanations and methods of solutions for the problem that I have been facing for such a long time by now.

I am working in a remote cluster where sudo command is not allowed and any operation on directories above $HOME branch is not permitted 
(`$HOME=/storage/5/trentalove`)

I need to configure

```
$HOME/external/trentacoollime
```

with boost library, which I installed in `$HOME/boost_1_65_1` using the boost_1_65_1.tar.bz2 source from http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_65_1.html

(Please note that `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` is not allowed.)

Then, I define my PATH variable in .bash_profile and export as
`export PATH = $HOME/boost_1_65_1:$PATH'

However, when I configure in $HOME/external/trentacoollime directory, with

```
./configure
```

I was prompted with an error message

> configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version>=1.41.0

When I configure with

```
./configure --with-boost=../../boost_1_65_1
```

It gave me no error message and successfully configured.

My guess is that since I defined and exported the PATH variable to the boost directory, I need not have the `--with-boost=../../boost_1_65_1` option when I execute the `./configure` command. However, I needed it.

Could someone explain what I am missing?

p.s. I did the same thing in my own machine with `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, which installed boost_1_65_1 under `/usr/include` directory. 
Then I could still configure the `$HOME/external/trentacoollime` with just `./configure` and no `--with-boost=` option ($PATH being defined in the same way as in the cluster).
However, please note that I can not implement the same strategy in the cluster since I do not have permission for sudo nor any kind of mv, cp, ln command to `/usr/include`, which is at a higher branch than my `$HOME` directory.

Comment: What made you think that adding something to PATH has any effect on build environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PATH has no effect on autotools (except maybe to find binaries to execute during the configure process).

You need to supply `--with-boost` regardless, unless your specific project has made other arrangements. Sometimes they employ `pkg-config` or pick up a dedicated environment variable (like `BOOST_DIR`, or `BOOST_ROOT`).

I don't think either of these is popular with autotools based projects.